# Breadcrumbs for jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, breadcrumbs

I have a tree of data and am trying to create a breadcrumbs to add navigation  path  to navigate through jstree nodes. I am not sure why my method is not producing what i expect

is it possible?

thanks
abdul

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share some code and the expected output...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/korchev/nktUe/8/ same like this but for jstree, in the given link they have used some kendoTree but i need it for jstree

Comment: At least add a fiddle version and try yourself something if fail then return to us :)

Comment: You got any solution @AbdulRazzakT